# top most common/duplicate elements over a time period in realtime

Tags: algorithm, nginx, go, data-structures

***I have user-generated strings coming in at an undefined rate, some of which is duplicate data, and I'd like to keep the count of the top-20 most common duplicates in real time, over a given constant time period (e.g., over the last hour), in Go.***

*The number of unique strings is not limited in any way, so, to avoid DoS, the datastructure probably has to have a defined size of the most number of elements (e.g., top-10k-elements and/or 1MB overall size), and drop the least recently inserted elements if they don't have any duplicates yet (but never drop any newly incoming elements!).*

My understanding is that this is exactly how [`ngx_http_limit_req_module.c`](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c) is [implemented](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c#ngx_http_limit_req_rbtree_insert_value), and this method is referred to in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) as “leaky bucket”, however, the [wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) page appears to suggest that it's the new data that'd be dropped from the queue, not the old one, so, not sure if the concept applies.

Regardless, I tried looking for a “leaky bucket” implementation in Golang, and by far the most popular result I found is [`uber-go/ratelimit`](//github.com/uber-go/ratelimit), whose API doesn't appear to fit my problem statement at all — it simply implements some actual rate-limiting queue, not a top X over the last Y count in realtime.

Can anyone suggest the proper name for what I'm looking for, and the best way to accomplish this, preferably in Go?

Comment: To search in realtime in your corpus you will need datastructure with predictable search/insert time like balansed binary tree or hashmap or sorted array at least. You can compact this structure periodicaly. I'd suggest Bloom filter which has constant search/insert time and constant size and several implementations in Go.

Comment: Do you need exact counts, or will probabilistic estimates be sufficient?

Comment: I am curious if someone who thinks that this is off topic could explain why it doesn't fit https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  The question asks for an *algorithm* for the *specific programming problem* of how to keep a real time top-20 list of terms showing up in user searches.  This is *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development* - find me anyone else who would want to solve this kind of problem!  It is none of the 6 kinds of problems that are not on topic despite fitting the initial criteria.  So why did 4 people conclude that it is off topic?

Comment: @btilly, I'd prefer an exact count, subject to the same conditions as documented of the nginx implementation, that the least-recently-inserted element (hopefully, one that also doesn't currently have any duplicates at all) gets the boot.

Comment: @cnst The nginx implementation is described at https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/.  The least-recently-inserted bit can be kept track of in an lru cache.  Google turned up https://github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru for a sample implementation.  But do note that the fact that nginx throttles active IP addresses reduces how much data they need to track, and also they do not try to track for an hour.  You probably want to somehow limit how much information you need to keep track of for this feature.

Answer (score -1):

This is two problems.

1. Keeping track of names that you've chosen to keep track of.
2. Noticing names that are trending that aren't in your list to keep track of.

For the first problem I'd recommend keeping track per name, per minute, how many there were.  As they finish, add them to a running total, and add to a queue of things to subtract back out in an hour.  This gives you 60 small objects per name, and on a running basis you'll be keeping a hash going.

The second problem is more challenging.  For this I'd use a probabilistic approach.  The idea is that each name is hashed with a unique id, and you keep only the thousand smallest hash values (and associated names) that you see in a minute.  (I'll give an algorithm for that in a minute.)  Your hash values should be evenly distributed among the 2^64 largest independently of the name, so common names will eventually show up in this list.  When they do, you start counting them!  (You will lose the first few, but with more work you can estimate how many you missed.  This optimization may be more work than it is worth though.)

Now how do we keep the thousand smallest hash values?  You use a *priority queue*, which is often implemented with a *heap* to create an updatable data structure where it is easy to pull out the largest hash value.  So you run the following pseudo-code.

```
create your priority queue of (hash, name)
for each name:
   hash hash of name and unique new id
   entry = (hash, name)
   if queue size < 1000:
       insert entry
   else if hash is smaller than the current max in the queue
      insert entry
      remove the largest entry
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you know how nginx implements this?  The docs don't appear to mention any sort of probabilistic uncertainties.

Comment: @cnst I answered that above.  The probabilistic design here allows this to be carried out with limited memory requirements even if the number of individual search terms is extremely large. And on a large cluster it can be adapted to allow the computation to be carried out and then merged on many machines.  But depending on your problem, it may be overkill.